# SpringBoot rest api giving 406 Bad request only when i am passing anystring.application in path variable

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot, path-variables

I have simple rest api, which gets all data from db according to the params passed in path variable.
Api is working fine unless i pass anystring.application in sectionId path variable. Any thing other than that will give output. When i debug , flow goes inside , and on return statement it give error. I commented service and repository call and return custom response , and this time also, on return statement i got 406.
So i think basically issue is in request.

This is my API,

```
@GetMapping("/{language:.+}/{sectionId:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, String>>>> find(@PathVariable String language,@PathVariable String sectionId,

        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

        Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,String>>> output = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String,Map<String,String>> firstInner = new HashMap<>();

        Map<String,String> secondInner = new HashMap<>();

        secondInner.put("secondInner", "sccondInner Value");

        firstInner.put("firstInner", secondInner);

        output.put("main output", firstInner);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(output,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Any help will be appriciated, Thanks.

Edit: When i am commenting @EnableWebMvc from my configuration class.Code is working. Can anyone tell the reason behind it?

Comment: 406 is not bad request code.

Comment: @Viet , yes it is for Not Acceptable

Comment: does your controller use `produces = APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` or similar thing?

Comment: Don't you need to escape the dot in your regex: {sectionId:\d+\.\d+}

Comment: @Viet no i am not using that.

Comment: @androberz Okay  i will try with that

Comment: @androberz, Tried, your solution, it is Giving 404 not found

Comment: Hitting this url works for me http://localhost/app-name/23/12